# VS2008 error with recursive C# class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a class within VS2008 written in C#. The class is recursive.

When I nan instance of this class and view it whilst debugging, VS2008 stalls for a few seconds and then the debug session exits.

Any ideas what the problem might be.

The class is

```
public class TextSection
{
    private bool used;
    private string id;
    private HL7V3_CD code;
    private string title;
    private string text;

    public List<TextSection> section;


    public TextSection()
    {
        used = false;
        section = new List<TextSection>();
    }

    public bool Used
    {
        get { return used; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            used = true;
            title = value;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            used = true;
            text = value;
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            used = true;
            id = value;
        }
    }

    public HL7V3_CD Code
    {
        get { return Code; }
        set
        {
            used = true;
            code = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging a screenshot of VS2008 before it exits is shown [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jKN88updjac/TpVIVlsai4I/AAAAAAAAAOc/AE9NapyVAk0/h301/Screenshot+-+12_10_2011+%252C+08_52_12.png)

Comment: what's this HL7V3_CD..  and that screen shot is very very small couldnt read anything from that.

Comment: OK - I see now that the screenshot is too small. I'll try better next time :-)  The problem has been answered now.

Comment: Jeyanth - the HL7V3_CD is a different type defined elsewhere in the project. ( It's actually a class to represent a HL7 V3 Coded Value )

Comment: @Jehof - I will, but the system has a time limit on how soon you can accept a question.

Comment: Note: Use another format for naming your variables (like adding a leading underscore aka. private HL7V3_CD _code) to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this property

```
public HL7V3_CD Code
{
    get { return Code; }
    set
    {
        used = true;
        code = value;
    }
}
```

It will generate a StackOverflowException, when the debugger tries to get the value from property Code, cause Code calls itself instead of returning the value of a variable

Comment: ahhh! That's embarassing  :-)

Answer (score 6):

You should change this segment

```
public HL7V3_CD Code
{
    get { return Code; }
    set
    {
        used = true;
        code = value;
    }
}
```

to

```
public HL7V3_CD Code
{
    get { return code; }
    set
    {
        used = true;
        code = value;
    }
}
```